# Network manager in Swift

Tags: json, swift, database, swiftui, networkmanager

i am trying to create a CRM app, for this i created a database on my raspberry Pi, and used PHP to create JSON results on a url.

Now i have created the following Network manager in swift, but the invalidData error at the end in the catch keeps getting thrown. What am i doing wrong ?

```
import Foundation

final class NetworkManager {
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    static let baseURL = ""
    private let buyersURL = baseURL + ""
    
    private init(){}
    
    func getBuyers(completed: @escaping (Result<[Buyer], CRMError>) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: buyersURL) else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidURL))
            return
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url)) { data, response, error in
            if let _ = error {
                completed(.failure(.unableToComplete))
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                completed(.failure(.invalidData))
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode(BuyerResponse.self, from: data)
                completed(.success(decodedResponse.request))
            }  catch {
                completed(.failure(.invalidData))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

The following is the result of the JSON on the URL

[image: JSON result]

and the following is my Buyer struct:

```
import Foundation

struct Buyer: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable{
    let id: Int
    let user_id: Int
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let country: String
    let phone: String
    let second_phone: String
    let whishes: String
    let budget: String
    let timing: String
    let fase: String
    let media: String
    let plans: String
    let extra: String
    let hot: Int
}

struct BuyerResponse : Codable {
    let request: [Buyer]
}
```

And this is the view in which i call get the buyers:

```
struct BuyersView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = BuyersViewModel()

    @State var path = NavigationPath()
    
    @State private var buyers: [Buyer] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack{
                CategoryView(categories: viewModel.fases, currentSelection: $viewModel.currentFase)
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink("Add buyer", value: 0)
                        .padding()
                }
                List(buyers){ buyer in
                    BuyerCellView(buyer: buyer)
                }
            }
//            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
//                AddBuyerView(path: $path, fases: viewModel.fases, medias: $viewModel.media)
//            }.navigationDestination(for: Buyer.self) { buyer in
//                BuyerDetailView(buyer: buyer)
//            }
        }.onAppear{
             getBuyers()
        }
    }
    
    func getBuyers() {
        NetworkManager.shared.getBuyers { result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case .success(let buyers):
                    self.buyers = buyers
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked that the variables on the JSON and the struct of Buyer are the same, but the error keeps happening, i just expect that the variable buyers returns a list of Buyers from the JSON.

I folowed the tutorial of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1oC7sLIgpI&t=22362s at around 6 hours into the video

Thank you for helping in advance

Comment: Before `completed(.failure(.invalidData))`, add `print("Error thrown while trying to decode JSON: \(error)")`. It should give you important info.

Comment: But seeing the JSON, I don't see `"request"` in your JSON (if that's really the one you are getting from your HTTP request), please add `print("Received: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")` to see what you really receive. `let id: Int` it seems to be a `String`, not a `Int`, see the double quotes around the JSON response. Same for `user_id`, etc.

Comment: Reconfirming, according to your json data, `id`, `user_id` and `hot` are String **not Int**. So try changing your `Buyer` struct.
Also there is no `request`, so use `let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode([Buyer].self, from: data)` directly.

Comment: Rather than throwing a `CRMError`, your catch statement instead threw an `Error`, namely, `completed(.failure(error))`, then the error would tell you exactly why the JSON decoding failed. Right now, you are discarding the meaningful error produced by `JSONDecoder` that tells you exactly why it failed.

Comment: You can replace the `.onAppear` and the `@StateObject` with `.task` which does the same thing. Then you can make `NetworkManager` a struct and make `getBuyers` async throws. These changes should get you on the right track for Swift and SwiftUI development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inside of `BuyerResponse` you say that the JSON should look like this:

```
{ request: [{buyer 1 properties}, {buyer 2 properties}] }
```

But judging from your screenshot, the response looks like this:

```
    [{buyer 1 properties}, {buyer 2 properties}]
```

Inside of your PHP script you should adjust the response so that you get that `request:`  before the list starts. That should do the trick.

Another way would be to change that line here

```
let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode(BuyerResponse.self, from: data)
```

to

```
let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode([Buyer].self, from: data)
```

That way you tell the decoder that it's getting a list of `Buyer`s without anything around it.

Generally if you get an error at that position, it means that the data that you receive does not match the data structure that you specify.

A good way to approach this is to just create a model struct with only one property and check whether that works. Then add another property, etc. If it doesn't work: print the error you receive and that will tell you at what line of the JSON there is something unexpected.